# Google indexing returns me a 403 PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: google-indexing-api, google-indexing

I have a problem in my production site with google indexing when perform an index via API.
I receive the following error message after I send the payload to google API.
I've verified and I'm the owner in console.google.com or search.google.com

```
Statuscode: Forbidden. Content: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Failed to verify the URL ownership.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
```

It worked for some time but starting from 2 days it started to give this error, I don't know where to look.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This error commonly occurs when the API request does not have the necessary permissions to verify ownership of the URL